# How do I make a map function return a single value rather than an array?

Tags: javascript, function, object, dictionary, react-native

The original idea with the function below was that it should return the card (an object) only if the ID matched, however, it didn't return anything (it returned undefined):

```
showDetails(cards, id){
  cards.map(function(card, index){
    if(card.id==id){
      console.log(card);
      return card;
    }
  })
}
```

Then I realized that I had the scope of return wrong and that I needed to return what the loop returned, so I came up with this:

```
showDetails(cards, id){
  return (cards.map(function(card, index){
    if(card.id==id){
      return card;
    }
  }))
}
```

The result of the code above is: [undefined, Object]

I just want this function showDetails to return the object, not an array.

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) with early exit.

```
function showDetails(cards, id) {
    var result;
    cards.some(function(card) {
        if (card.id === id) {
            result = card;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Or use an ES6 method [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
function showDetails(cards, id) {
    return cards.find(function(card) {
        return card.id === id;
    });
}
```

Comment: You talk about `Array#every`, but use `some()` shortly after. Is it a typo, or I misunderstood something?

Comment: i mean [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), of course.

Comment: you can even use filter for keeping only the desired elements of array

Comment: @ManjeetSingh, filter returns an array as well, but op does not wand an array.

Comment: @NinaScholz, yeah you are right but if filter is returning an array with single element we can easily convert that to object by array[0],

Comment: @ManjeetSingh, then you have to iterate all objects.